# Update query using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join, common-table-expression

Why I get the following syntax error in this section of stored procedure :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

---

```
WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime
    AS
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM #Residence
    )
    UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.over_time = t1.over_time + CONVERT(TIME, CAST(CTE_Residence_Overtime.overtimeHours AS VARCHAR(2))  
    FROM r_overtime AS t1
    INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime 
    ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE_Residence_Overtime.[dayDate];
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing parentheses on that `CONVERT()`

Comment: Correct your parentheses!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing one bracket

```
WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime
    AS
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM #Residence
    )
    UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.over_time = t1.over_time + CONVERT(TIME, CAST(CTE_Residence_Overtime.overtimeHours AS VARCHAR(2)))  
    FROM r_overtime AS t1
    INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime 
    ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE_Residence_Overtime.[dayDate];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing paren on the `set`:

```
    SET t1.over_time = t1.over_time +
                       CONVERT(TIME,
                               CAST(CTE_Residence_Overtime.overtimeHours AS VARCHAR(2)
                                   )  
                              )
------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

One missing parenthesis can make your life quite hectic!

```
WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime
        AS
        (
          SELECT * 
          FROM #Residence
        )
        UPDATE t1 
        SET t1.over_time = t1.over_time + CONVERT(TIME, CAST(CTE_Residence_Overtime.overtimeHours AS VARCHAR(2)))  
        FROM r_overtime AS t1
        INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime 
        ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE_Residence_Overtime.[dayDate];
```